# Change Project Task / Issue Stage odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I only can change task or issue stage in kanban view drag and drop, any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can also change it by clicking the stages in form view. Under project configuration you can change the visibility of stages, too (folded).